# Join on multiple tables one query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 5 tables pages, articles, text, images and videos.

**My question is how can I get**

**page-(pk)pageId**

**articles-(pk)articleId,(fk)pageId.**

```
SELECT pageTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle) 
FROM pages 
JOIN articles ON articles.pageId = pages.pageId 
GROUP BY pageTitle
```

RESULTS: GOOD

[image: joinPagesArticlesResult]
**to join with:**

**articles(pk)articleId**

**text-(fk)articleId**

**images(fk)articleId**

**videos(fk)articleId**

```
SELECT pageTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle) AS articleTitle, 
group_concat(textId) AS textId, group_concat(text) AS text, 
group_concat(imageId) AS imageId,group_concat(imageLoc) AS imageLoc , 
group_concat(videoId) AS videoId,group_concat(videoLoc) AS videoLoc 
FROM articles 
JOIN pages ON pages.pageId = articles.pageId  
JOIN text ON text.articleId = articles.articleId
JOIN images ON images.articleId = articles.articleId
JOIN videos ON videos.articleId = articles.articleId
GROUP BY pageTitle
```

RESULTS: MISSING TYSON1 from GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle)

[image: joinTextImagesVideos]

**I want to be able to join all on one table. As well as get tyson1 to display in query. Not sure why it's not displaying. Im not sure if im doing the right type of join, if I need two SELECT statements to get this data, or if im not doing alias correctly.**

The columns in each table go as follow

pages:

[image: Page columns]

articles:

[image: Article Columns]

text:

[image: Text Columns]

images:

[image: Image Columns]

Videos:

[image: Videos Columns]

Comment: Just a Warning: You are using INNER JOIN, so if there are no match between the rows of both tables, they will be skipped, thats why "Tyson1" disappears. For example, an article that don't have images or videos, wont appear on your query. Read about LEFT JOIN and when to use it.

Comment: I didn't understand what side each table was on. I thought I was getting all the data from the tables with the join looked over this once you told me about the left join http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-left-join/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next query that use left join:

```
SELECT
    pageTitle,
    GROUP_CONCAT(articleTitle) AS articleTitles,
    GROUP_CONCAT(textId) AS textIds,
    GROUP_CONCAT(text) AS texts,
    GROUP_CONCAT(imageId) AS imageIds
    GROUP_CONCAT(imageLoc) AS imageLocs,
    GROUP_CONCAT(videoId) AS videoIds,
    GROUP_CONCAT(videoLoc) AS videoLocs
FROM
    articles
JOIN
    pages ON pages.pageId = articles.pageId
LEFT JOIN
    text ON text.articleId = articles.articleId
LEFT JOIN
    images ON images.articleId = articles.articleId
LEFT JOIN
    videos ON videos.articleId = articles.articleId
GROUP BY
    pageTitle
```